# Avoid automatic alphabetical sorting MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a simple table I am populating with PHP and MySQLi. The table only consists of one field that I have set to be the primary key to avoid duplicates. Every thing is working correct except that MySQLi is sorting the inputs in alphabetical order even though I do not put them into the database this way. I want to pull from the table later, and have everything echo out in the exact order I put the items in the database.

Is there a way to accomplish this easily? Will I have to use a different field as the primary key?

```
$mysqli = connect_db();
$mysqli->query('TRUNCATE TABLE things');
$things = [bat, cat, apple, zero];
for($i = 0; $i < count($things); $i++){
    $query = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO things (name) VALUES (?)');
    $query->bind_param('s', $things[$i]);
    $query->execute();
    $query->close();
}
$mysqli->close();

// The table puts them in the following order: apple, bat, cat, zero
```

Comment: so just add `ORDER by ID` when you select

Comment: Why do you keep `prepare`ing the query inside the loop? About your question: How do you get the data out of the database when they are not ordered as you want?

Comment: I don't have an ID field. I keep preparing the query because I am binding the different values and executing the query. Is there a way to execute and insert every value in the array at once without the for loop?

Comment: Rows should be considered *unordered* unless you explicitly specify an order.  If you care about the original insert order, add and sort by an auto-incrementing ID or add a `created` timestamp column.  Don't rely on the DBMS to give you order when you didn't ask for any.

Comment: @cHao great point. I was trying to keep the table simple, but I guess I have to add an id field.

Comment: @BlakePlumb: What TheWolf is saying is, you only have to prepare the statement once.  Then you can loop over your items, and just do the bind and execute for each item.  That's actually the real point of prepared statements: to build a query once and be able to run it over and over without the server having to parse it each time.  Preventing SQL injection is just a really spiffy side effect.

Comment: @cHao I didn't know that was how it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to add an `INT AUTO_INCREMENT` field to your table structure. You can then `ORDER BY` your id field when outputting. With this done, you can add rows to your table like this:

```
$things = [bat, cat, apple, zero];
$val = '';
$query = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO things (name) VALUES (:name)');
$query->bind_param(':name', $val); // $val is bound by reference!

for($i = 0; $i < count($things); $i++){
    $val = $things[$i];
    $query->execute();        
}

$query->close();
$mysqli->close();
```

Disclaimer: I usually work with PDO, so no guarantee this code is working perfectly. It's just to get the idea of preparing the statement once and then bind and execute in the loop.

Comment: I didn't use your code exactly, but thank you for helping me understand the concept.

Answer (score 1):

This is how supposed be, because the field is primary key, so that its an index that MySQL justify it as to be sorted (a-z) or (1-n) when its index and only one field. You can add another field (Id as INT and Primary key) then change your field to UNIQUE index.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$things = array('bat','cat','apple','zero');
foreach($things as $thing) {
    // $thing = bat, cat, apple, zero 
}
```

edit:
just saw you don't have an id field, add one! id(int 11) auto_increment primary_key etc, then you should be away laughing